# How to use boolean value returned by a method

Tags: java, android

I just want to know how to use a boolean value returned from a method.This is the method which is returning the value:

```
 public  boolean hasConnection() {
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) MCQ.this.getBaseContext().getSystemService(
                Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

            NetworkInfo wifiNetwork = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
            if (wifiNetwork != null && wifiNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
              return true;
            }

            NetworkInfo mobileNetwork = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
            if (mobileNetwork != null && mobileNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
              return true;
            }

            NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
              return true;
            }

            return false;
          }
```

This is the method where i want to use this value:

```
public void setScrollViewLayoutMarginBottom()
     {
         Resources resources = this.getResources();
          DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();

          Boolean b = hasConnection();

         if(b == true)
         {
             px = 90 * (metrics.densityDpi/160f); 
         }
         else
             px = 60 * (metrics.densityDpi/160f); 


         layoutParams.bottomMargin = (int) px;
            layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, (int) px);
            sv.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
     }
```

Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are already using the value retured. are you getting any compiler errors??

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear what you want to do, and what's not working.

Comment: well, you could get rid of the temporary `Boolean` by just doing `if(hasConnection())`, but otherwise, I don't see a problem.

Comment: Note that the returned value is of type `boolean`, and not `Boolean`. There's no reason to transform the primitive value into an object. And if `(b == true)` is ugly. Just use `if (b)`.

Comment: actually i am not getting the exact value returned by the first method.Even if the first method is returning false,Boolean b remains equal to true.

Comment: @user1662334: no way. Use a debugger and see what happens. There's no way that b is true if the method returned false.

Comment: @JB Nizet sir,i got the reason of the problem.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're already using the return value, although you're boxing it into a `Boolean` instead of just using `boolean` for no particular reason - and you're explicitly comparing it with `true`, which is unusual.

I'd probably use a conditional operator instead, actually:

```
int scale = hasConnection() ? 90 : 60;
px = scale * (metrics.densityDpi / 160f);
```

Comment: Yes sir,this was the problem.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

You dont' need to save the return value in a variable, just use it directly.
if(booleanValue == true) will be true or false, so just remove the == true, it's obsolete

```
     if(hasConnection()) {
         px = 90 * (metrics.densityDpi/160f); 
     } else {
         px = 60 * (metrics.densityDpi/160f); 
     }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for solving the problem sir.